# How to make Android LinearLayout to clip its children content?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout (horizontal) with several child TextViews inside. I have set fixed layout_width for both the LinearLayout and all the TextViews. When the total width of the children exceeds the width of the layout, it automatically shrink the children, making them narrower, which is not what I want. I want the layout to clip the children content and keep their width.
How can I achieve that?

For example: Let's say my LinearLayout is 200dp wide, and there are 4 TextView each 60dp wide. I want it to show the first three TextViews, and 1/3 of the 4th (60 + 60 + 60 + 20 = 200)

Thanks.

Comment: Paste your code

Answer (score 0):

- Use `android:weightSum` in `LinearLayout`
- And use `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` in `TextView`

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:weightSum="10">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="hello"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="hello"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="hello"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="hello"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Also**

You can change `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in `TextView` .

**Edit**

**And you can use in your java code .**

You can change the width or weight by yourself .

```
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
private int viewsCount = 4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < viewsCount; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        if(i == viewsCount-1){
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
        } else {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3);
        }
        mLinearLayout.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your 1st solution will show the first three TextViews and hide the subsequent ones. And it still divides the LinearLayout space evenly between the first three, which is not my case. I want LinearLayout to keep my TextView at the specified width, showing as much content as it can, clipping the rest. E.g. Let's say my LinearLayout is 200dp wide, and there are 4 TextView each 60dp wide. I want it to show the first three TextViews, and 1/3 of the 4th.
p.s. I could do this with RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout, but want to do with LinearLayout.

Comment: You can set weight for `3,3,3,1`.

Comment: If you don't want to average of last `textview` .You can use `<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"/>` .

Comment: That might work if you know your set of TextView beforehand. However, the number of TextView as well as their widths are not known when the layout is created. More TextView can be added later on. Each might be with a different width. Do you mean we need to re-calculate the weight every time there is an update?

Comment: Yes ,you can use

Comment: I'm sorry but that solution seems not what I want. I'd like a LinearLayout which can take care of the clipping itself, without re-calculating the weight. Thanks anyway. The layout_weight is good to know.

Comment: Good luck to you .@ScottD